# $k^n +1 \equiv 0 \pmod{n^2}$

Tags: number-theory

> Find $n>1$ such that $k^n +1 \equiv 0 \pmod{n^2}$ where $k$ is a prime.

I didn't know how to deal with $n^2$ and the fact that $k$ is prime. Should we split this into the cases that $\gcd(k,n) = 1$ and $\gcd(k,n) \neq 1$?

Comment: $n$ is prime or $k$ is prime???

Comment: Note that this amounts to finding a solution to the equation
$$
k^n + xn^2 - 1 = 0
$$
for a fixed prime $k$ where $x,n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: @barakmanos The question says $k$ is a prime.

Comment: We know that $\gcd(k,n)=1$. For contradiction, let $\gcd(k,n)>1$ and let $p$ be a common prime divisor of $k,n$. Since $k^n+1=tn^2$ for some $t\in\mathbb Z$, we get $p\mid tn^2-k^n=1$, contradiction.

Comment: Then, clearly $n$ is not divisible by $k$.

Answer (score 1):

I will show that there are infinitely many solutions, i.e., pairs $(p,n)$ such that $p$ is prime, $n\ge 2$ is integer, and $p^n \equiv -1\pmod{n^2}$. Note that $p\nmid n$.

By Euler's theorem we know that $p^{\varphi(n^2)} \equiv 1\pmod{n^2}$, and by the above also $p^{2n} \equiv 1\pmod{n^2}$. It follows by Knuth lemma that
$$
p^{\mathrm{gcd}(\varphi(n^2),2n)} \equiv 1\pmod{n^2}.
$$

At this point, suppose $n=q^m$, for some odd prime $q\neq p$. Then there exists a primitive root $g$ in $\mathbf{Z}/n^2\mathbf{Z}$, and let us denote by $j$ the unique exponent in $\{1,\ldots,\varphi(n^2)\}$ such that $p\equiv g^j\pmod{q^{2m}}$. It follows that
$$
j \mathrm{gcd}(\varphi(q^{2m}),2q^m) \text{ divides }\varphi(q^{2m}),
$$
that is equivalent to
$
2jq^{2m-1} \text{ divides }(q-1)q^{2m-1},
$
i.e., $j$ divides $\frac{q-1}{2}$.

To obtain our solutions, let $q$ be a prime $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and choose $j=\frac{q-1}{4}$. Then, by Dirichlet's theorem there exist infinitely many primes $p\equiv g^j\pmod{q^{2m}}$.

Comment: You could add that $\gcd\left(p,n^2\right)=1$ because $p^n\equiv -1\pmod{n^2}$, which is necessary for Euler's theorem, though it's trivial. Also, you don't need to know Knuth's lemma. If you know about modular arithmetic, notice $\text{ord}_{n^2}(p)\mid \phi\left(n^2\right),2n$ if and only if $\text{ord}_{n^2}(p)\mid \gcd\left(\phi\left(n^2\right),2n\right)$.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid writing $\mathrm{ord}_{n^2}(p)$ :D Anyway, I realize now that the above question could have another meaning: Do we have to find $n\ge 2$ such that $n^2\mid p^n+1$, with $p$ prime being fixed?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti For any prime $p$, find an $n \geq 2$ such that $p^n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{n^2}$.